# Django deployed in IIS is not working with Selenium

Tags: python, django

I have a Django web app hosted in IIS with a function using selenium that automates the transfer of data from another application. It runs when I run it on my localhost, however with IIS it doesn't even pull up the browser.

I pasted the code that pulls up a website I need:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def transfer(request):

    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('http://localhost/virtus#scorecard/rateteammember')
    browser.set_page_load_timeout(10)
```

I am using windows 10 and IIS version 10.0.15063.0

I am also using ChromeDriver version 2.42.591088 that says 'Only local connections are allowed' which I think is the source of the problem.

Can someone please advise what to do next.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?